# Running a command with specific environment settings - one-liner

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

To run a program with custom env settings, we do this on Linux

```
$ MYVAR=23 ./foo.py
```

On Windows, the only way I know of is:

```
C:\> set MYVAR=23
C:\> .\foo.py
C:\> REM unset MYVAR here (but how?)
```

But can't this done be as an one-liner?

Comment: Perhaps this question would be better suited for the folks at ServerFault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set foo=bar&.\foo.py&set foo=
```

It should be noted that batch files are parsed one line at the time, so one liners like this are problematic there (setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION can help out in those cases)

Comment: `&` means the next command will be run on command success (and not failure)?

Comment: & always runs the next command, && is success only and || for failure

Answer (score 1):

```
set MYVAR=
```

Will unset it.

You can also use `SETLOCAL` and `ENDLOCAL` to limit the scope of your variables.  Run `help SETLOCAL` and `help GETLOCAL` from the command line for more info.

Also check out the [Cmd reference](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5FB255FF-72DA-4B08-A504-1B10266CF72A&displaylang=en).